# How can I call the type of kicks in football (soccer) in one or two words?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms, sports

Corner kick, free kick, penalty kick — how can I call those kicks? "Deadplay kicks", "fixed kicks"?

Is there any special naming for this type of kicks?

Comment: hhh3112, the "how can I call" wording is incorrect in English. You should replace the *how* with *what*. You would benefit from reading the discussion at this link http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150325/how-do-we-call-something-in-english

Comment: Hi, every so often I go through posts which have "How do you call....?" or "How are ______ called?"  in their questions or titles. See the discussion in this post: [“How do we call (something) in English?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150325/how-do-we-call-something-in-english) Would you mind editing your title to *“**What** do you call the type ....?”* Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about [*set piece*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_piece_%28football%29)?

> The term **set piece** or **set play** is used in association football and rugby to refer to a situation when the ball is returned to open play following a stoppage, particularly in a forward area of the pitch. Most often, the term is used to refer to free kicks and corners, but sometimes throw-ins.

Seeing that a penalty is a type of free kick, that should cover all your cases.

Wiktionary has this [usage example](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/set_piece):

> Roberto Carlos is deadly from set pieces.

Comment: It's a good answer but if a goalie had a free-kick, for example, you wouldn't call it a set piece.

Comment: To me this meaning of *set piece* comes from the fourth meaning [here](http://www.yourdictionary.com/set-piece), because as that wikipedia article says, *set pieces are one area where tactics and routines can be worked out in training in advance of matches* - so it's to do with the fact that players can plan in advance what to do (rather than having to think on their feet, literally), and the term refers to the ensuing play rather than just the kick itself.

Answer (score 1):

**Deadball kicks** would be the straightforward answer - or **deadball plays** if you include throw-ins as well.

If it's a planned move (as with a corner, or an attacking free-kick or throw-in) then it's a **set piece** - that would usually be an attack on goal.

Answer (score -1):

"Football kicks"? Or for Americans — "soccer kicks"?